# Heroku - An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

While trying to deploy a class project to heroku, I received the following error:

```
  An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.

  Failed to install gems via Bundler.

  Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3


  Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

After doing some investigation I found that `sqlite3` does not run on Heroku, and I need to set up `postresql` instead, and specify development/deployment in my Gemfile like so:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
end
```

However, I am still getting the same error. I am doing this for a school project, so I this is my first try at Heroku and I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails as well. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: After you fix this problem, you maybe will get the next error with the asset pipeline precompile stuff.. For fixing that, simple add gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

Are you pushing the correct branch to Heroku? Make sure that you're on the master branch, and that your changes have been committed.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Commit message."  
$ git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the right track. Have you run bundle locally and committed Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to your git repository? Also, you can replace sqlite3-ruby with just sqlite3 (and then no require is necessary).

```
bundle install
git add Gemfile
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Update database gem environments."
git push heroku master
```